# Add all Engine's factory paths dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In `support/factory_bot.rb` we add all the Engine's factory paths like this:

```
require 'factory_bot'
FactoryBot.definition_file_paths.unshift(
  MyEngine::One.factory_path, 
  MyEngine::Two.factory_path,
  SomethingElse.factory_path, 
)
FactoryBot.find_definitions

if defined? RSpec
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  end
end
```

Is there a way to dynamically add all my Engine's factory paths in? For example, if we were to add a new engine, we wouldn't need to make any adjustments to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to dynamically add all the factory paths with the following:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'factory_bot'

factory_paths = []

Rails::Engine.subclasses.each do |klass|
  engine = klass.name.chomp('::Engine')
  if engine.constantize.methods.include?(:factory_path)
    factory_paths << engine.constantize.factory_path
  end
end

FactoryBot.definition_file_paths.unshift(*factory_paths)

FactoryBot.find_definitions

if defined? RSpec
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  end
end
```